# Filter Dataset using where column is not a number using Spark Java API 2.2?

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs

I'm new in Spark Java API. I want to filter my Dataset where a column is not a number. My dataset ds1 is something like this.

```
+---------+------------+
|  account|    amount  |
+---------+------------+
| aaaaaa  |            |
| aaaaaa  |            |
| bbbbbb  |            |
| 123333  |            |
| 555555  |            |
| 666666  |            |
```

I want return a datset ds2 like this:

```
+---------+------------+
|  account|    amount  |
+---------+------------+
| 123333  |            |
| 555555  |            |
| 666666  |            |
```

I tried this but id doesn't work for me.

```
 ds2=ds1.select("account"). where(dsFec.col("account").isNaN());
```

Can someone please guides me with a sample spark expression to resolve this.

Comment: you can write a udf function to check for the digit or not

Comment: How can I use it please? Can you guide me with a sample expression?

Comment: I have tried to answer below using udf function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a `udf` function to check whether the string in `account` column is numeric or not as

```
    UDF1 checkNumeric = new UDF1<String, Boolean>() {
        public Boolean call(final String account) throws Exception {
            return StringUtils.isNumeric(account);
        }
    };

    sqlContext.udf().register("numeric", checkNumeric, DataTypes.BooleanType);
```

and then use `callUDF` function to call the `udf` function as

```
    df.filter(callUDF("numeric", col("account"))).show();
```

which should give you

```
+-------+------+
|account|amount|
+-------+------+
| 123333|      |
| 555555|      |
| 666666|      |
+-------+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Just cast and check if result is null:

```
ds1.select("account").where(dsFec.col("account").cast("bigint").isNotNull());
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this:

Scala Equivalent:

```
import scala.util.Try
df.filter(r => Try(r.getString(0).toInt).isSuccess).show()

+-------+------+
|account|amount|
+-------+------+
| 123333|      |
| 555555|      |
| 666666|      |
+-------+------+
```

Or You can use the same using Java's try catch:

```
df.map(r => (r.getString(0),r.getString(1),{try{r.getString(0).toInt; true
                }catch {
                      case runtime: RuntimeException => {
                        false}
                      }
            })).filter(_._3 == true).drop("_3").show()

+------+---+
|    _1| _2|
+------+---+
|123333|   |
|555555|   |
|666666|   |
+------+---+
```